# Guava's Files.move() does it move the files or copy it

Tags: java, multithreading, file, guava

I have to move huge number of file(almost 60 MB each) from folder A to folder B. Folder B is a i/p folder for a a Spring scheduled task. it picks those files and start processing in parallel. I am using Guava's file utility methods to move the files.

```
Files.move(sourceFile,targetFile,Charsets.UTF_8);
```

I do see error in my TaskScheduler class that the file is not there to read

> at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
>   at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.lineIterator(FileUtils.java:1856) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
>   at com.varun.processor.readFile(Processor.java:342) ~[classes/:?]

My hunch is that File is in copying and hence Spring scheduled thread couldn't acquire the lock to read it.As per Guava's doc it says its move method behave like mv command on unix but I see code as copy in guava jar.

[image]

Can anyone suggest a better way to move files on unix system from spring app Where o/p directory is i/p for another downstream process.

Comment: It only copies if the `renameTo` fails.

Comment: This is also how `mv` works. If it can't move the file in-place, it will create a copy and then delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

moving files with Guava works fine.  you just have to keep trying to read the file until it succeeds.

I tested moving a file with size 525 MB and Guava moved it in less than 1 second.

see below for an example (I intentionally added a delay before moving the file, so the file processor will try to open the file before and while it was being moved) :

```
import com.google.common.io.ByteSource;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 * <dependency>
 * <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
 * <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
 * <version>22.0</version>
 * </dependency>
 */
public class GuavaFileMoveExample {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("GuavaFileMoveExample");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        GuavaFileMoveExample a = new GuavaFileMoveExample();
        a.doTheWork();
    }

    private void doTheWork() throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(new FileMover());
        executorService.submit(new FileProcessor());
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }
}

class FileMover implements Callable<Void> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("FileMover");

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        moveFile();
        return null;
    }

    private void moveFile() {
        final File sourceFile = new File("/tmp/origin/ideaIU-2016.3-no-jdk.tar.gz");
        final File targetFile = new File("/tmp/destination/ideaIU-2016.3-no-jdk.tar.gz");

        try {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "started moving file");
            Files.move(sourceFile, targetFile);
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "finished moving file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "ioexception while moving file ", e);
        }

    }
}

class FileProcessor implements Callable<Void> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("FileProcessor");

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        readBinaryFile("/tmp/destination/ideaIU-2016.3-no-jdk.tar.gz");

        return null;
    }

    private byte[] readBinaryFile(String aFileName) {
        File file = new File(aFileName);
        ByteSource source = Files.asByteSource(file);


        byte[] result = null;
        while (result == null) {
            try {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "started reading file");
                result = source.read();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "finished reading file. size: " + result.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // expected if file is not yet at destination
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "error reading file", e);
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```